# build error Qt-SQL-driver-plugin for SQLite-DB with SQLCipher-extension for Qt

Tags: qt, sqlite, sqlcipher

[Step-by-step guide to build Qt-SQL-driver-plugin for SQLite-DB with SQLCipher-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29196087/step-by-step-guide-to-build-qt-sql-driver-plugin-for-sqlite-db-with-sqlcipher-ex)

On Step-5 running ./configure I get this error message

Codes@Codes-PC /c/temp/sqlcipher-master
$ ./configure --prefix=$(pwd)/dist --with-crypto-lib=none --disable-tcl CFLAGS=
"-DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC -DSQLCIPHER_CRYPTO_OPENSSL -I/c/openssl-win32/include /c/te
mp/sqlcipher-master/libeay32.dll -L/c/temp/sqlcipher-master/ -static-libgcc" LD
FLAGS="-leay32"

checking build system type... i686-pc-mingw32

checking host system type... i686-pc-mingw32

checking for gcc... no

checking for cc... no

checking for cl.exe... no

configure: error: in `/c/temp/sqlcipher-master':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See`config.log' for more details

Comment: Which OS are you working on?

Comment: I'm assuming you have visual studio installed?  If so did you use the command prompt that came with visual studio? ("Visual Studio Command Prompt", found in the tools section of Visual Studio start menu folder).  IF you are not using visual studio, what compiler are you using?  If you are using mingw, type gcc at the command prompt and see what happens.  I'm guessing that you will get something link "gcc is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Comment: I am using mingw, you are right I get the message "gcc is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: I suggest to reinstall MinGW from scratch following this page: https://wiki.qt.io/MinGW

Comment: Reinstalled but no luck

Comment: Try to find where gcc.exe is and thta folder to the system path

Comment: sorry it's my bad, there is a space in the file path