# Compile error QSQLCIPHER driver plugin for Qt

Tags: qt, sqlite, makefile, qt5, sqlcipher

[Step-by-step guide to build Qt-SQL-driver-plugin for SQLite-DB with SQLCipher-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29196087/step-by-step-guide-to-build-qt-sql-driver-plugin-for-sqlite-db-with-sqlcipher-ex/31581219#31581219)

On step-6 Compile the QSQLCIPHER-driver-plugin for Qt, executing `mingw32-make` I got an error message.

I can't understand the error:

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.4.2\5.4\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\sqlcipher>mingw32-make

mingw32-make -f Makefile.Release all

mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sq
ldrivers/sqlcipher'

mingw32-make[1]: *** No rule to make target '.moc/release/smain.moc', needed by
'.obj/release/smain.o'.  Stop.

mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sql
drivers/sqlcipher'

makefile:38: recipe for target 'release-all' failed

mingw32-make: *** [release-all] Error 2
```

Makefile

```
    #############################################################################
# Makefile for building: qsqlcipher
# Generated by qmake (3.0) (Qt 5.4.2)
# Project:  sqlcipher.pro
# Template: lib
# Command: C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/bin/qmake.exe -o Makefile sqlcipher.pro
#############################################################################

MAKEFILE      = Makefile

first: all
install: release-install debug-install 
uninstall: release-uninstall debug-uninstall 
QMAKE         = C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/bin/qmake.exe
DEL_FILE      = rm -f
CHK_DIR_EXISTS= test -d
MKDIR         = mkdir -p
COPY          = cp -f
COPY_FILE     = cp -f
COPY_DIR      = cp -f -R
INSTALL_FILE  = cp -f
INSTALL_PROGRAM = cp -f
INSTALL_DIR   = $(COPY_DIR)
DEL_FILE      = rm -f
SYMLINK       = 
DEL_DIR       = rmdir
MOVE          = mv -f
SUBTARGETS    =  \
        release \
        debug


release: FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release
release-make_first: FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release 
release-all: FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release all
release-clean: FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release clean
release-distclean: FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release distclean
release-install: FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release install
release-uninstall: FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release uninstall
debug: FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug
debug-make_first: FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug 
debug-all: FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug all
debug-clean: FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug clean
debug-distclean: FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug distclean
debug-install: FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug install
debug-uninstall: FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug uninstall

Makefile: sqlcipher.pro ../../../../.qmake.conf ../../../../mkspecs/win32-g++/qmake.conf ../../../../mkspecs/features/spec_pre.prf \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/qdevice.pri \
        ../../../../mkspecs/features/device_config.prf \
        ../../../../mkspecs/common/shell-unix.conf \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/qconfig.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_axbase.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_axbase_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_axcontainer.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_axcontainer_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_axserver.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_axserver_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_bluetooth.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_bluetooth_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_bootstrap_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_clucene_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_concurrent.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_concurrent_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_core.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_core_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_dbus.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_dbus_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_declarative.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_declarative_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_designer.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_designer_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_designercomponents_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_enginio.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_enginio_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_gui.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_gui_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_help.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_help_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_location.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_location_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_multimedia.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_multimedia_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_multimediawidgets.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_multimediawidgets_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_network.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_network_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_nfc.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_nfc_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_opengl.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_opengl_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_openglextensions.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_openglextensions_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_platformsupport_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_positioning.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_positioning_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_printsupport.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_printsupport_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qml.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qml_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qmldevtools_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qmltest.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qmltest_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qtmultimediaquicktools_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_quick.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_quick_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_quickparticles_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_quickwidgets.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_quickwidgets_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_script.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_script_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_scripttools.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_scripttools_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sensors.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sensors_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_serialport.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_serialport_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sql.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sql_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_svg.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_svg_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_testlib.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_testlib_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_uitools.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_uitools_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_webchannel.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_webchannel_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_webkit.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_webkit_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_webkitwidgets.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_webkitwidgets_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_websockets.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_websockets_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_webview.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_webview_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_widgets.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_widgets_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_winextras.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_winextras_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_xml.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_xml_private.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_xmlpatterns.pri \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_xmlpatterns_private.pri \
        ../../../../mkspecs/modules-inst/qt_plugin_qsqlcipher.pri \
        ../../../../mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qsqlcipher.pri \
        ../../../../mkspecs/features/qt_functions.prf \
        ../../../../mkspecs/features/qt_config.prf \
        ../../../../mkspecs/features/win32/qt_config.prf \
        ../../../../mkspecs/win32-g++/qmake.conf \
        ../../../../mkspecs/features/spec_post.prf \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/qmodule.pri \
        ../../../../mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf \
        ../../../../.qmake.conf \
        ../../../../mkspecs/features/exclusive_builds.prf \
        ../../../../mkspecs/features/default_pre.prf \
        ../../../../mkspecs/features/win32/default_pre.prf \
        ../../../3rdparty/sqlcipher.pri \
        ../../../sql/drivers/sqlcipher/qsql_sqlite.pri \
        ../../../../mkspecs/features/qt_build_paths.prf \
        ../../../../mkspecs/features/qt_targets.prf \
        ../../../../mkspecs/features/qt_common.prf \
        ../../../../mkspecs/features/qt_plugin.prf \
        ../qsqldriverbase.pri \
        ../../../../mkspecs/features/resolve_config.prf \
        ../../../../mkspecs/features/exclusive_builds_post.prf \
        ../../../../mkspecs/features/default_post.prf \
        ../../../../mkspecs/features/c++11.prf \
        ../../../../mkspecs/features/cmake_functions.prf \
        ../../../../mkspecs/features/create_cmake.prf \
        ../../../../mkspecs/features/qt_example_installs.prf \
        ../../../../mkspecs/features/exceptions_off.prf \
        ../../../../mkspecs/features/qt_docs_targets.prf \
        ../../../../mkspecs/features/win32/rtti.prf \
        ../../../../mkspecs/features/precompile_header.prf \
        ../../../../mkspecs/features/warn_on.prf \
        ../../../../mkspecs/features/qt.prf \
        ../../../../mkspecs/features/resources.prf \
        ../../../../mkspecs/features/moc.prf \
        ../../../../mkspecs/features/win32/windows.prf \
        ../../../../mkspecs/features/testcase_targets.prf \
        ../../../../mkspecs/features/yacc.prf \
        ../../../../mkspecs/features/lex.prf \
        sqlcipher.pro \
        ../../../../mkspecs/features/data/cmake/Qt5PluginTarget.cmake.in \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/lib/Qt5Sql.prl \
        C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/lib/Qt5Core.prl
    $(QMAKE) -o Makefile sqlcipher.pro
../../../../mkspecs/features/spec_pre.prf:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/qdevice.pri:
../../../../mkspecs/features/device_config.prf:
../../../../mkspecs/common/shell-unix.conf:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/qconfig.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_axbase.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_axbase_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_axcontainer.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_axcontainer_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_axserver.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_axserver_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_bluetooth.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_bluetooth_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_bootstrap_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_clucene_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_concurrent.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_concurrent_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_core.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_core_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_dbus.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_dbus_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_declarative.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_declarative_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_designer.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_designer_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_designercomponents_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_enginio.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_enginio_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_gui.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_gui_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_help.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_help_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_location.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_location_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_multimedia.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_multimedia_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_multimediawidgets.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_multimediawidgets_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_network.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_network_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_nfc.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_nfc_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_opengl.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_opengl_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_openglextensions.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_openglextensions_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_platformsupport_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_positioning.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_positioning_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_printsupport.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_printsupport_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qml.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qml_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qmldevtools_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qmltest.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qmltest_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qtmultimediaquicktools_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_quick.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_quick_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_quickparticles_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_quickwidgets.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_quickwidgets_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_script.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_script_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_scripttools.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_scripttools_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sensors.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sensors_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_serialport.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_serialport_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sql.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sql_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_svg.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_svg_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_testlib.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_testlib_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_uitools.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_uitools_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_webchannel.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_webchannel_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_webkit.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_webkit_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_webkitwidgets.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_webkitwidgets_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_websockets.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_websockets_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_webview.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_webview_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_widgets.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_widgets_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_winextras.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_winextras_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_xml.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_xml_private.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_xmlpatterns.pri:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_xmlpatterns_private.pri:
../../../../mkspecs/modules-inst/qt_plugin_qsqlcipher.pri:
../../../../mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qsqlcipher.pri:
../../../../mkspecs/features/qt_functions.prf:
../../../../mkspecs/features/qt_config.prf:
../../../../mkspecs/features/win32/qt_config.prf:
../../../../mkspecs/win32-g++/qmake.conf:
../../../../mkspecs/features/spec_post.prf:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/qmodule.pri:
../../../../mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:
../../../../.qmake.conf:
../../../../mkspecs/features/exclusive_builds.prf:
../../../../mkspecs/features/default_pre.prf:
../../../../mkspecs/features/win32/default_pre.prf:
../../../3rdparty/sqlcipher.pri:
../../../sql/drivers/sqlcipher/qsql_sqlite.pri:
../../../../mkspecs/features/qt_build_paths.prf:
../../../../mkspecs/features/qt_targets.prf:
../../../../mkspecs/features/qt_common.prf:
../../../../mkspecs/features/qt_plugin.prf:
../qsqldriverbase.pri:
../../../../mkspecs/features/resolve_config.prf:
../../../../mkspecs/features/exclusive_builds_post.prf:
../../../../mkspecs/features/default_post.prf:
../../../../mkspecs/features/c++11.prf:
../../../../mkspecs/features/cmake_functions.prf:
../../../../mkspecs/features/create_cmake.prf:
../../../../mkspecs/features/qt_example_installs.prf:
../../../../mkspecs/features/exceptions_off.prf:
../../../../mkspecs/features/qt_docs_targets.prf:
../../../../mkspecs/features/win32/rtti.prf:
../../../../mkspecs/features/precompile_header.prf:
../../../../mkspecs/features/warn_on.prf:
../../../../mkspecs/features/qt.prf:
../../../../mkspecs/features/resources.prf:
../../../../mkspecs/features/moc.prf:
../../../../mkspecs/features/win32/windows.prf:
../../../../mkspecs/features/testcase_targets.prf:
../../../../mkspecs/features/yacc.prf:
../../../../mkspecs/features/lex.prf:
sqlcipher.pro:
../../../../mkspecs/features/data/cmake/Qt5PluginTarget.cmake.in:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/lib/Qt5Sql.prl:
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/mingw491_32/lib/Qt5Core.prl:
qmake: FORCE
    @$(QMAKE) -o Makefile sqlcipher.pro

qmake_all: FORCE

make_first: release-make_first debug-make_first FORCE
all: release-all debug-all FORCE
clean: release-clean debug-clean FORCE
    -$(DEL_FILE) C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/Src/qtbase/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlcipher.a
distclean: release-distclean debug-distclean FORCE
    -$(DEL_FILE) Makefile

html_docs:
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) prepare_docs && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) generate_docs

docs:
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) html_docs && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) qch_docs

release-install_html_docs:
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release install_html_docs
install_html_docs: release-install_html_docs

release-uninstall_html_docs:
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release uninstall_html_docs
uninstall_html_docs: release-uninstall_html_docs

release-install_qch_docs:
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release install_qch_docs
install_qch_docs: release-install_qch_docs

release-uninstall_qch_docs:
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release uninstall_qch_docs
uninstall_qch_docs: release-uninstall_qch_docs

release-install_docs:
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release install_docs
install_docs: release-install_docs

release-uninstall_docs:
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release uninstall_docs
uninstall_docs: release-uninstall_docs

release-qch_docs:
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release qch_docs
qch_docs: release-qch_docs

release-prepare_docs:
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release prepare_docs
prepare_docs: release-prepare_docs

release-generate_docs:
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release generate_docs
generate_docs: release-generate_docs

release-mocclean:
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release mocclean
debug-mocclean:
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug mocclean
mocclean: release-mocclean debug-mocclean

release-mocables:
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release mocables
debug-mocables:
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug mocables
mocables: release-mocables debug-mocables

check: first
FORCE:

$(MAKEFILE).Release: Makefile
$(MAKEFILE).Debug: Makefile
```

Comment: This is definitely a Makefile issue. please post the relevant Makefiles...

Comment: Makefile added to the main questian

Comment: I got a clue when running qmake, it don't make the 'smain.moc' file in the dir .moc/release, so run `qmke -d` option at the end of execution I got the message
 'DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/moc.prf:38: flow control
statement 'return', aborting block'

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing inverted commas at the end of the third line in the smain.cpp file.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: I know, but I can't.