# How to use SQLCipher in QT

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt, dll, sqlcipher

I am trying to use SQLCipher within my QT C++ project. I am running a windows machine and I have used steps explained in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40378921/4169913) (until end of step 5) to generate my `sqlite3.h`, `sqlite3.c`, `sqlcipher.exe` and `sqlite3.dll`. Hopefully, now I have an executable that works fine but I am trying to make use of SQLCipher within my QT project. I want to add `sqlite3.h` and `sqlite3.dll` to my project and use its functions to work with databases. I have copied `sqlite3.h` and `sqlite3.dll` from `sqlcipher-master` into my project. My `.pro` file looks like this:

```
HEADERS +=\
sqlcipher/sqlite3.h \
myOtherHeaderFiles.\
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -DSQLITE_OS_WIN=1 -DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC -DSQLITE_TEMP_STORE=2 -ldl -lpthread
LIBS+="path\to\project\sqlite3.dll"
```

When I try to build my project no compiling error occurs but when I try to run it I get:

```
11:55:15: Starting path\to\project\build-project-Desktop_Qt_5_14_1_MinGW_32_bit-Debug\project.exe ...
11:55:15: The program has unexpectedly finished.
11:55:15: The process was ended forcefully.
11:55:15: path\to\project\build-project-Desktop_Qt_5_14_1_MinGW_32_bit-Debug\project\build-project-Desktop_Qt_5_14_1_MinGW_32_bit-Debug\project.exe crashed.
```

Do I miss something important? Do I copy the wrong files or is there anything more to add to my project before building it? if you have had the experience of using SQLCipher in a QT+mingw project please leave a comment or guide me through.

Comment: "crashed" could mean anything. Run it under a debugger so we can at least see the crash location or cause. Do you get any useful error if you run the program directly?

Comment: @Botje I tried to run my `.exe` using `QT console`. It said `sqlite3.dll` not found. I copied the file into the folder and now it runs. I have used a static path in my `.pro` to `.dll` file, so I was expecting it to run without a problem. It seems like the problem is solved. I will try to test encryption and leave another comment.

Comment: Windows executables only store the module name (=filename) of dependent libraries, not the full path. At runtime you are at the mercy of the [library search order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order)