# How use SqlCipher in Qt database

Tags: qt, encryption, sqlcipher

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZRmH.png)I am trying to use SqlCipher as a free way to encrypt a database and use it in a QT project. I am using version 4.8 of QT and SQLite 3.0 I think.

I have not been able to find a good example to build this SqlCipher DLL and to incorporate it into a QT project. One example needed libeay32.dll & libeay32.lib for win32. However that seemed to be another rabbit hole to build that. Does anyone have experience with this?

These are my error messages

Comment: Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40378921/3365136 maybe it can help

Comment: Tried this one. Have not gotten too far. Always errors with tclsh.exe and it making use of this. don't know why this is an issue.

Comment: error message:
$ make sqlite.c
tclsh /c/temp/sqlcipher-master/ext/fts5/tool/mkfts5c.tcl
make: *** [fts5.c] Error 53